# Converging Electric Fields on Metal Plate

Tags: dc, conductors, electric-field

I have a question, but I'm not a trained engineer, just curious. So bear with me on my explanation.

Let's say I have a metal plate.
I have DC power supply and I connect the positive electrode on one side of the plate, and the negative electrode on the opposite side. Now I get a different DC power supply and I connect this one's positive electrode next to the first DC power supply's negative electrode, and the same on the opposite side with the second electrodes. Both DC power sources supply the same amount of power.

My question is: What would happen to the converging electric fields on the metal plate?

Comment: you might need to draw a diagram, as your word picture is ambiguous. By 'side', assuming the plate has one dimension much smaller (thickness tending to zero), do you mean 'face' or 'edge'? Does each power supply deliver the same voltage? I would assume the supplies deliver enough current to maintain their terminal voltage, and that the plate does not fail due to heat. You can get voltages by symmetry, and then they, and their position derivative electric fields, add linearly, superposition is your friend.

Comment: I mean the edge of the plate. Yes, both power supply have the same voltage.

Comment: And yes the assumption is that the plate does not fail due to heat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear from your question whether you have a cis or trans arrangement for the electrodes, but let's answer them both. These diagrams would be far prettier as the output of a field solver than my unsteady hand with paint, but at least the general feel is correct.

Let's assume a uniform square plate, with small electrodes attached at the (roughly) 25% and 75% points of opposing sides. Let's assume each independent power supply delivers 2V. Although the supplies are floating, symmetry dictates that each supply will settle to giving +V and -V at its two output poles with respect to the mid point of the plate, which I'll refer to as my local ground or 0 V reference.

The first diagram shows the cis condition, where the same polarities are on the same sides.
[image]

The black lines indicate current flow. The more lines, the higher the current. Equipotentials will be at right angles to the flow of current everywhere. I've shown the obvious (by symmetry) 0 V equipotential as a green line.

I originally wrote 'The top and bottom boundaries of the plate will a little less than +V and -V, as there is little current flowing along the boundary'. However, from my symmetry arguments, I think I should now say 'The section of boundary between the same sign connections is an equipotential'. The potential on the edge boundary between the opposite signs will change more or less linearly from +V to -V. The entire top half of the plate is above zero volts, the bottom half below zero.

The second diagram shows the trans conditions, where the polarities are swapped.

[image]

Again the green lines show 0 V equipotentials. Current flow black lines again cross these at right angles. More current flows vertically than horizontally.

Although the supplies are isolated from each other, you have specified in your OP that they supply the same power, so symmetry is dictated, which ensures that each supply has the same current magnitude at each pole. The entire top right and bottom left quadrants are at a voltage above zero, the others are below zero.

There is a very elegant way of arriving at the correct result without a field solver, but you do have to really believe in superposition to be convinced by it (which engineers are). A single isolated pole in an infinite plate with ground at infinity has a trivial field pattern. You can get the result for two poles on an infinite plate by merely superposing the fields for two individual poles. We can get from an infinite plate to a finite plate by noting the boundary condition that no current flows across the edge of the plate. We therefore add lines of mirror symmetry, adding an infinite number of 'reflections' of the four poles you require, to realise these boundary conditions. The final field is then a superposition of the infinite number of trivial single pole fields, which tends to converge quite quickly. Look up [Method of Image Charges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_image_charges) if you're intrigued by this.

Comment: Nice use of paint

Comment: Thank you for your awesome answer. I appreciate it.